# После обновления адаптера ViewPager пропадает пункт меню

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewpager, menuitem

У меня есть `ViewPager`, в котором 4 отдельных фрагмента, в первом фрагменте я реализовал `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_chapter, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search.getActionView();
    search(searchView);
}
```

В методе `onCreateView` я добавил `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` чтобы иконка отображалась только тогда, когда выбран этот фрагмент.

В этом фрагменте у меня список глав с кнопками "избранное", в методе обработчика кнопки по мимо всего прочего я обновляю адаптер `ViewPager`:

```
 ((MainActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).updateViewPagerAdapter();
```

и как только кликну иконка поиска пропадает с тулбара, не обновлять адаптер не получается, а при обновлении она пропадает, как быть?

Comment: Вызов метода родителя через `super` переместите в начало. Проблему наверное не исправит, но я так как у вас нигде не видел

Comment: @Flippy а как оно должно быть? Через интерфейсы? P.S. метод super перемещал.

Comment: Это происходит из-за вызова методов жизненного цикла нескольких фрагментов при обновлении адаптера. В итоге `onCreateOptionsMenu` вызывается не только у отображаемого фрагмента, но и у левого и правого. При чём отображаемый фрагмент будет в начале или в середине списка вызовов, засим меню перезапишется из других фрагментов. Выход - переопределить `setUserVisibleHint` и в нём `invalidateMenu` когда фрагмент видим - должно помочь.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в других фрагментах нет метода `onCreateOptionsMenu`. У меня структура приложения такая: MainActivity > ViewPager > ViewPagerAdapter > 4 фрагмента, в каждом фрагменте RecyclerView и собственный адаптер, 1 и 2 фрагменты, должны взаимодействовать, если произошли изменения в 1 то 2 должен обновиться и также обратно. И также должны взаимодействовать 3 и 4 фрагменты между собой. И в первом фрагменте список глав, через который можно перейти в новое активити, в новом активити могут быть изменены все 4 списка из 4 фрагметов, соответственно при возвращение в MainAcitivity я должен внести

Comment: @ЮрийСПб изменения, и я не заморачивался, и просто у адаптера ViewPager вызывал notifyDataSetChanged(), но так как изменения могли и не происходить, или произойти лишь в одном пункте списка, думаю не целесообразно обновлять все. Так что сейчас все методы notifyDataSetChanged всех списков и ViewPager удалил, и теперь встал вопрос, как все это правильно обновлять, проблема не в понимании кода, а в понимании структуры, как это все должно обновляться на должном уровне?